# CKEditor - throws 404 page not found error

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, http-status-code-404, outsystems

I am trying to embed the CK Editor in an Outsystems application, where the editor works fine for initial instances. When I try to edit the content that already exists, it works fine for some instances and then all of a sudden when I edit and save it throws '404-page not found' error.

1. I am not able to find exactly, when this error shoots up.
2. I am still wondering about the maximum character size that can be in a CKEditor.(As I was not able to find the official maximum limit, different people have specified different count)

Any hints to fix this issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you embedding CKEditor by yourself or using CKEditor component from [OutSystems' network](http://www.outsystems.com/NetworkSolutions/ProjectDetail.aspx?ProjectId=97)?

Comment: I am using the component provided by Outsystems.

Comment: And are you attempting to use several instances of CKEditor on the same page or use it and refresh the place where it is using an *Ajax Refresh*?

Comment: Use it and refresh the place where it is using Ajax refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original CKEditor component made available by André Ramos in the OutSystems Network has some limitations, namely lack of support for multiple instances on the same page and other problems when replaced through an AJAX request.

Check if the modified versions by António Chinita address your issues (see [here](http://www.outsystems.com/NetworkForums/ViewTopic.aspx?TopicId=5953&Topic=%5b%5b%5dCKEditor%5d-Discussion#Post26870) and [here](http://www.outsystems.com/NetworkForums/ViewTopic.aspx?TopicId=5953&Topic=%5b%5b%5dCKEditor%5d-Discussion#Post27497)). They are available in the component's discussion thread.